# Docker: Oracle database 18.4.0 XE wants to configure a new database on startup

Tags: oracle, docker

I'm trying to configure an Oracle Database container. My problem is whenever I'm trying to restart the container, the startup script wants to configure a new database and failing to do so, because there already is a database configured on the specified volume.

What can I do let the container know that I'd like to use my existing database?

The start script is the stock one that I downloaded from the Oracle GitHub:
[Link](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0/runOracle.sh)

UPDATE: So apparently, the problem arises when `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c start` returns that no database has been configured, which triggers the startup script to try and configure one.

UPDATE 2: I tried creating the db without any environment variables passed and after restarting the container, the database is up and running. This is an annoying workaround, but this is the one that seems to work. If you have other ideas, please let me know

Comment: you are not providing enough information like, what script does your instalation use?. It does not look like a docker problem but something related to that script.

Comment: I didn't tell you, because it is the one the docker image comes with. I'll try to get it out and paste it. The image is built right from the oracle github with no changes

Comment: From your edit I'm guessing that you are using https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/c699ebf5c74ee10be6ea6e46a975486f464683ac/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0/Dockerfile.xe and this file has instructions on how to build your docker image properly, did you follow this instructions? how did you build your dockerfile?

Comment: I followed the instructions as close as I could, which was not hard. I used the `buldDockerImage.sh` script, where I selected the 18.4.0 version, and the XE edition. The .rpm file passed the checksum test as well. The fresh start worked as expected. I could reach the database with SQL Developer, I created a user, I logged in with that, it was normal. I just can't fire it up again because of the issue stated above.

Comment: I would recommend to you the opening of an issue on the oracle github about your specific problem, I'm sure that they have more information about your specific problem and if there is a bug it would help other before you when they fix it.

Comment: I found an issue since then on their github and I linked this thread on there, hope it helps. Also, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the source of the problem from start to finish.

The thing I overlooked in the [documentation](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance) is that the Express Edition of Oracle Database does not support a SID/PBD other than the default. However, the configuration script (seemingly `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c`, but not surly) was only partially made with this fact in mind. Which means that if I set the `ORACLE_SID` and/or `ORACLE_PWD` environmental variables when installing, the database will be up and running, with 2 suspicious errors, when trying to copy 2 files.

```
mv: cannot stat '/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/dbs/spfileROPIDB.ora': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/dbs/orapwROPIDB': No such file or directory
```

When stopping and restarting the docker container, I'll get an error message, because the configuration script created folder/file names according to those variables, however, the docker image is built in a way that only supports the default names, causing it to try and reconfigure a new database, but seeing that one already exists.

I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should connect to the linux image with:

docker exec -ti containerid bash

Once there you should check manually for the following:

if  $ORACLE_BASE/oradata/$ORACLE_SID exists as it does the script and if $ORACLE_BASE/admin/$ORACLE_SID/adump does not.

Another thing that you should execute manually is

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c start | grep -qc "Oracle Database is not configured
```

UPDATE AFTER COMMENT=====

I don't have the script but you should run it with bash -x to see what is the script looking for in order to debug what's going on

What makes no sense is that you are saying that $ORACLE_BASE/admin/$ORACLE_SID/adump does not exist but if the docker deployed and you have a database running, the first time the script run it should have created this.

Comment: I did that, the `$ORACLE_BASE/oradata/$ORACLE_SID` exists, the `adump` does not. As I said in the original post, `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c start` returns that the database is not configured

Comment: after running with `bash -x` I found domething suspicous: https://pastebin.com/1fjN5fny You can see that at one point the configfile is null. I don't know why, but it is and that's what seems to cause the problem to me